# SOQL query on Event not working if record has more than one Contact related

Tags: apex

I have a code when I want to update an Event based on some data from other sObjects. If my Event has only one contact related it works fine but it assign two or more it gives me the following error:

> List has no rows for assignment to SObject

The error line is the one referring to

```
String visitaID= ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().containsKey('evid')?ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('evid'):'';
if(String.isEmpty(visitaID)){
    ApexPages.addmessage(new ApexPages.message(ApexPages.severity.ERROR,'No record found'));
} 
else{
    System.debug('visitaID: ' + visitaID);
    Event visita = [SELECT Id, BI_FVI_SurveyTaken__c,BI_FVI_Estado__c From Event Where Id = :visitaID];
    visita.BI_FVI_SurveyTaken__c = surveyID;
    visita.BI_FVI_Estado__c = 'Qualified';
    update visita;
}
```

The current user has access to the record and also to every field retrieved on the query so I don't know what may be causing this kind of issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: From where are you getting the `visitaID` ? It would be helpful if you could post the code for the same.

Comment: it could be causing by two things:
1) the user does not have access
2) the ID does not exist

Comment: @VijayGanji Edited with full code. I get the `visitaID` from an ApexPage parameter and it's entering on else and debugs the current recordId. But if I try this with a more than one related contact event it doesn't found any value on the query. Hope this helps and thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in your question, you are associating multiple contacts to an event i.e. you have enabled Shared Activities.

So when you enable shared activities, you will have to use  [EventRelation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api.meta/api/sforce_api_objects_eventattendee.htm) object to get the event information.

And the reason why you are getting results for your SOQL when you have only one contact associated to event is because, that contact will be the primary contact of that event. Whereas, when it is related to multiple contacts, that won't be the case.

Comment: I'm writting this query `List<EventWhoRelation> whoRelationLIST = [SELECT Id, EventId, Event.BI_FVI_SurveTaken__c, BI_FVI_Estado__c FROM EventWhoRelation WHERE EventId = :visitID];` but it's giving me the following error: ***Invalid type: EventWhoRelation***

Comment: Sorry I put the wrong sObject but even though it displays the same kind of error ***Invalid type: EventRelation***

Comment: I found the problem. The team was using a class with API Version 23. I updated it now because I didn't have fully access to the code before posting this question and now is working fine. Thank you anyway for your time and support!

Comment: Yes! I managed to query EventRelation records for that specific Event record. Thanks a lot!